# Tab-specific, non-intrusive notification in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension. When the user goes to the options page, they might modify a setting which will require them to refresh any tabs they have in which they're using the extension. So if the user changes one of these settings, then goes back to a tab which requires a refresh, I'd like to notify them of this in a non-intrusive way.

Is there a part of the API specifically for doing this sort of thing, or some other recommended way of doing it? I was thinking of maybe a little message that comes down from the top of the page, but can be closed, or a popup coming out of the browser action.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options.. To name a few:

1. **Do not require it.** As much as you can, make the (presumably) content script adapt to new settings. It's by far a better UX - in some cases.
2. Least intrusive would probably be to **update a browser action / page action icon** if you use one.

   Both APIs allow a per-tab change of icon/badge. You could also animate it a little to bring attention.
3. An **in-page notification** injected into the DOM. Some sort of toast or `<dialog>`.
4. Watch tab changes with `chrome.tabs` events, and do something on activation of affected tab, such as a **`chrome.notifications` notification**.